# Onclick listener in Recyclerview of Popup Window

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to Make Popup Window where the user can see Recyclerview(List of Comments). But I want to add 2 buttons in it for upvote and downvote for comments.

I have completed view of Recyclerview and its showing properly as I want but I can not add buttons in recyclerview. Here is my Code.

**Popup Window Code from my Activity:**

```
lateinit var  getAllcomment : GetAllCommentsAdapter
lateinit var upVote : View.OnClickListener
lateinit var downVote : View.OnClickListener

viewallcomments_txt.setOnClickListener {it->
            val layoutInflater = this@ViewSinglePostActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            val customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null)
            val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
            val size = Point()
            display.getSize(size)
            val popupWindow=PopupWindow(customView, size.x-50, size.y-660, true);
            popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
            popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation)
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(linearLayout1, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            customView.popup_rcv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            getAllcomment = GetAllCommentsAdapter(ArrayList(), upVote, downVote) // I have declare Adapter all parameter
            getMainApp().swiftAPI.getAllComments(post_id).enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<Comments>>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Comments>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@ViewSinglePostActivity, t?.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<Comments>>, response: Response<ArrayList<Comments>>) {
                    if (response?.isSuccessful!!){
                        getAllcomment.commentList.addAll(response.body()!!)
                        customView.popup_rcv.adapter = getAllcomment
                        getAllcomment.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            })
```

**GetAllcomments Adapter:**

```
class GetAllCommentsAdapter (var commentList: ArrayList<Comments>, val upVote: View.OnClickListener, val downVote: View.OnClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GetAllCommentsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    var comment_id = 0
    var commentHashMap = HashMap<Int, Int>()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.popup_rcv, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return commentList.count()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.comment?.setText(commentList.get(position).comment)
        holder.username?.setText(commentList.get(position).username)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var username : TextView ?= null
        var comment : TextView ?= null
        var upvote : ImageView ?= null
        var downvote : ImageView ?= null
        init {
            this.username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cmt_user_txt)
            this.comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_cmt_txt)
            this.upvote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.upvote_comment_img)
            this.downvote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.downvote_comment_img)
        }
    }
```

But I am getting this error when I open the popup window.

> lateinit property upVote has not been initialized

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error with your implementation, usually you should initialize a `var` at compile time, but with the `lateinit` keyword you promised the compiler that you would initialize it later when your application is running and that it should not flag an error during compilation, but you didn't keep to that promise, now when you try to use the variable you never initialized, you get an exception.

So the solution would be to provide an implementation for `upVote` and `downVote` click listeners before you use them.

Comment: Thanks sir you answer explained me where i was Wrong.